# How to determine xpath for pagination?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, pagination

Given below the HTML code of next button (pagination), kindly suggest xpath for pagination

```
<li class = "pagination-link next-link">
<a data-aa-region="srp-pagination" data-aa-name="srp-next-page"
<span>next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try following **xpath**.

```
//li[@class='pagination-link next-link']/a[./span[text()='next']]
```

OR

```
//li[@class='pagination-link next-link']/a[@data-aa-name='srp-next-page'] /span[text()='next']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)    
element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Next'")))    
print element.text
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```