# How to determine xpath using the following code?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, web-crawler

How to write xpath using the following code.

```
<span class="active-per-page">25</span>
<span class="active-per-page">50</span>
<span class="active-per-page">100</span>
```

I require xpath for `<span class="active-per-page">100</span>`

Answer (score 1):

**solution 1:**

```
//span[contains(text(),'100')]
```

**solution 2:**

```
//*[contains(@class, "active-per-page")  and contains(.,'100')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have order selectors or text matches in Xpath, see here https://devhints.io/xpath

In case you want to select the third span, the Xpath would be

```
//span[3]
```

In case you want to select the span with the text `100`, you could do like

```
//span[text()="100"]
```

Maybe you can be more precise what you want to select.

Comment: It is really helpful...Good Job...Another question for your comments ...https://stackoverflow.com/q/61231794/13294812

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

1. `//span[contains(text(),'100')]`
2. `//span[text()="100"]`
3. `//span[@class="active-per-page" and text()="100"]`
4. `//*[text()="100"]`